# Solving equations in .NET

Tags: c#, .net, math, conditional-statements, mathematical-optimization

I'm trying to solve some simple equations in .NET. I came across [Math.NET](http://www.mathdotnet.com/) and evaluate it.
The `Solver()` methods seemed to be what I need but I can't figure out how to use side conditions with this method.

To illustrate my problem I will give you a sample:

```
Given:  
0 <= a_i <= 100  
0 <= b <= 100
0 <= c
a_i, b and c are given

x_1, ..., x_n should be optimized

f(x) = x_1*a_1 + x_2*a_2 + ... + x_n*a_n = b

Side conditions:  
g(x) = x_1 + x_2 + ... + x_n = c  
0 <= x_i
```

Is it possible to solve such a problem using the solve method or any other component of Math.NET or do you know any (free for commercial use) .NET library that can be used for solving this?
I wouldn't like to write an algorithm for such a common problem by myself.

Best regards & thanks in advance

Comment: possible duplicate of [Free Optimization Library in C#](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1211201/free-optimization-library-in-c)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need an optimizer with constraints like simplex method or Marquardt non-linear optimization.

Comment: the problem looks rather linear to me ;) - right from the book, Simplex or interior Points are both fine for this - but is this really a answer?

Comment: You can't find what you're looking for unless you know its name.

Comment: I finally decided to port my Simplex I wrote once at university to NET, works fine :)

Answer (score 2):

[ALGLIB](http://www.alglib.net/) is great for these tasks. Check out their page on [constrained optimization](http://www.alglib.net/optimization/boundandlinearlyconstrained.php).

EDIT: It has both a free license (GPL) and a commercial license starting from $370.

Comment: thank - didn't check on this for some time - +1 for the reminder ;)

Answer (score 2):

IMHO [Microsoft Solver Foundation](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/solverfoundation/threads) is the way to go for this. The Express Version is free AFAIK and powerful enough for most smaller applications.

As I see now the Express Version is only indented for exploration - but there is (now?) a Standard-Lib for MSDN subscribers so I don't remove this post yet, as you might have a MSDN subscribtion.