# fminsearch in R is worse than in Matlab

Tags: r, matlab, optimization, fminsearch

There is my data (x and y columns are relevant):
https://www.dropbox.com/s/b61a7enhoa0p57p/Simple1.csv

What I need is to fit the data with the polyline. Matlab code that does this is:

```
spline_fit.m:
function [score, params] = spline_fit (points, x, y)

min_f = min(x)-1;
max_f = max(x);

points = [min_f points max_f];
params = zeros(length(points)-1, 2);

score = 0;
for i = 1:length(points)-1
    in = (x > points(i)) & (x <= points(i+1));
    if sum(in) > 2
        p = polyfit(x(in), y(in), 1);
        pred = p(1)*x(in) + p(2);
        score = score + norm(pred - y(in));
        params(i, :) = p;
    else
       params(i, :) = nan;
    end
end


test.m:
%Find the parameters
r = [100,250,400];
p = fminsearch('spline_fit', r, [], x, y)
[score, param] = spline_fit(p, x, y)

%Plot the result
y1 = zeros(size(x));
p1 = [-inf, p, inf];
for i = 1:size(param, 1)
    in = (x > p1(i)) & (x <= p1(i+1));
    y1(in) = x(in)*param(i,1) + param(i,2);
end

[x1, I] = sort(x);
y1 = y1(I);

plot(x,y,'x',x1,y1,'k','LineWidth', 2)
```

And this does work fine, producing following optimization: [102.9842, 191.0006, 421.9912]

I've implemented the same idea in R:

```
library(pracma);
spline_fit <- function(x, xx, yy) {

  min_f = min(xx)-1;
  max_f = max(xx);

  points = c(min_f, x, max_f)
  params = array(0, c(length(points)-1, 2));

  score = 0;
  for( i in 1:length(points)-1)
  {
    inn <- (xx > points[i]) & (xx <= points[i+1]);
    if (sum(inn) > 2)
    {
      p <- polyfit(xx[inn], yy[inn], 1);
      pred <- p[1]*xx[inn] + p[2];
      score <- score + norm(as.matrix(pred - yy[inn]),"F");
      params[i,] <- p;
    }
    else
      params[i,] <- NA;
  }  
  score
}
```

But I get very bad results:

```
> fminsearch(spline_fit,c(100,250,400), xx = Simple1$x, yy = Simple1$y)
$xval
[1] 100.1667 250.0000 400.0000

$fval
[1] 4452.761

$niter
[1] 2
```

As you can see, it stops after 2 iterations and doesn't produce good points.

I'll be very glad for any help in resolving this issue.

Also, if anyone knows how to implement this in C# using any free library, it will be even better. I know whereto get polyfit, but not fminsearch.

Comment: Are you aware that Matlab and R are different languages? A literal translation is not the way to go and I have no idea if the Matlab and corresponding R functions do the same. You should describe what you want to do for those of us R users that don't know much Matlab.

Comment: Matlab's [`fminsearch`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/fminsearch.html#f83-999399) is based on Nelder-Mead. Best I can tell, R's [`fminsearch`](http://www.inside-r.org/packages/cran/pracma/docs/fminsearch) uses Fletcher-Powell by default unless `dfree=TRUE` is set.

Comment: Is your question about why the R code is failing or where to find a C# optimization library that implements `fminsearch`? That latter is likely off-topic and you don't even have the appropriate tags. I suggest editing your question.

Comment: +1 for a reproducible example.

Comment: googled for "C# nonlinear Nelder-Mead": http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dn201752.aspx

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1211201/free-optimization-library-in-c-sharp

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The problem here is that the likelihood surface is very badly behaved -- there are both multiple minima and discontinuous jumps -- which will make the results you get with different optimizers almost arbitrary.  I will admit that MATLAB's optimizers are remarkably robust, but I would say that it's pretty much a matter of chance (and where you start) whether an optimizer will get to the global minimum for this case, unless you use some form of stochastic global optimization such as simulated annealing.

I chose to use R's built-in optimizer (which uses Nelder-Mead by default) rather than `fminsearch` from the `pracma` package.

```
spline_fit <- function(x, xx = Simple1$x, yy=Simple1$y) {

    min_f = min(xx)-1
    max_f = max(xx)

    points = c(min_f, x, max_f)
    params = array(0, c(length(points)-1, 2))

    score = 0
    for( i in 1:(length(points)-1))
    {
        inn <- (xx > points[i]) & (xx <= points[i+1]);
        if (sum(inn) > 2)
        {
            p <- polyfit(xx[inn], yy[inn], 1);
            pred <- p[1]*xx[inn] + p[2];
            score <- score + norm(as.matrix(pred - yy[inn]),"F");
            params[i,] <- p;
        }
        else
            params[i,] <- NA;
    }  
    score
}

library(pracma) ## for polyfit
Simple1 <- read.csv("Simple1.csv")
opt1 <- optim(fn=spline_fit,c(100,250,400), xx = Simple1$x, yy = Simple1$y)
## [1] 102.4365 201.5835 422.2503
```

This is better than the `fminsearch` results, but still different from the MATLAB results, and worse than them:

```
## Matlab results:
matlab_fit <- c(102.9842, 191.0006, 421.9912)
spline_fit(matlab_fit, xx = Simple1$x, yy = Simple1$y)
## 3724.3
opt1$val
## 3755.5  (worse)
```

The `bbmle` package offers an experimental/not very well documented set of tools for exploring optimization surfaces:

```
library(bbmle)
ss <- slice2D(fun=spline_fit,opt1$par,nt=51)
library(lattice)
```

A 2D "slice" around the `optim`-estimated parameters.  The circles show the optim fit (solid) and the minimum value within each slice (open).

```
png("splom1.png")
print(splom(ss))
dev.off()
```

[image]

A 'slice' between the matlab and optim fits shows that the surface is quite rugged:

```
ss2 <- bbmle:::slicetrans(matlab_fit,opt1$par,spline_fit)
png("slice1.png")
print(plot(ss2))
dev.off()
```

[image]

Comment: Wow, now that's an answer.

Comment: @ben-bolker, I've tried this `optim` function and got following [result](https://www.dropbox.com/s/yk9ou1itmfudan7/Rplot.png). Black dots are original data, blue dots are approximation. What is strange is the last line (x = 422..500), which is clearly too high. Why polyfit is producing such high line?
There is complete [code](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/5153956/test.r)

Comment: it would probably take longer than I have to go over the details, but ... you can see that there are a few scattered points above the main line of points.  Going through the range of parameter space required to move that line down from the scattered points to the main line would presumably require the algorithm to traverse a locally suboptimal region, which it can't do.  You can try `optim(...,method="SANN")`, but be aware that it might need some tuning.  Or use differential evolution (http://cran.r-project.org/package=DEoptim).

Comment: Hi, @BenBolker! Actually it's plotting problem, not results. I've just checked and second plot has different scale, that's why it looks offset. Check [this](https://www.dropbox.com/s/y6xhqxymwstpsmw/Rplot2.png) out, it's almost perfect fit (using 5 segments, not 4)