# from Matlab to C#: what should I use to replace fsolve?

Tags: c#, matlab, numerical-methods

I have to convert a Matlab script to C#. The matlab code uses fsolve() to find the fixed point of a function.

```
function Pr2=adiab(Pr1,Tr1,Pv1,Tv1,Pv2,k,kv,Vv,Vr)
    Pr2=(Pr1^(1/k)-Vv/Vr*Tr1/Tv1*Pr1^((1-k)/k)*(Pv2^(1/kv)/Pv1^((1-kv)/kv)-Pv1))^k;
end
% ...
Prav(i+1)=fsolve(@(Pr2) Pr2-adiab(Prav(i),Trav(i),Pa,Ta,Pr2,k,kv,Vvt,Vrt),Prav(i));
```

I know I need a numerical solver but there are so many I don't know which method is best suited for this problem.

- [Math.NET](http://numerics.mathdotnet.com/api/MathNet.Numerics.RootFinding/index.htm) has a bunch of root finding algorithms.
- [Numerical](https://numerical.codeplex.com/) has methods to solve non-linear equations:

  > ## Non Linear Equations Solving
  >
  > - Newton's method
  > - Secant method
  > - Half Division method
  > - Chord method
- I can't use [alglib](http://www.alglib.net/commercial.php): the free version has a GPL license, the commercial one is too expensive.

Comment: Did you look into other questions which ask for C# solver libraries? see e.g. http://stackoverflow.com/a/1217567/678093; another possibility is to call Matlab from C#: http://de.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_external/call-matlab-function-from-c-client.html

Comment: I've used [alglib](http://www.alglib.net/) in the past and would recommend it

Comment: Numerical implements many solving methods for specific problems. I don't know which kind my problem needs.